# Find selected segment in custom from custom segment

Tags: ios, swift

I made a custom segment control from a UIView, and I need to find a way to find out the selected segment. Could I use `segmentedControl.attributedSelectedTitles` to find the selected segment, and if so how can I convert that to a string?

Comment: 1. Extend `UIControl`, not `UIView`. 2. Show your code.

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
segment.selectedSegmentIndex
```

Which will give you a zero-based position of the segment. That means the first segment has an index of 0, the second has an index of 1, etc.

Comment: is there a way I could get that into a string or should I use case for that